# Gridview row command event is not changing the ASP. Page conrol behaviour

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview3 in aspx page in asp.net.I have bound the gridview  with data soure

Gridview has row button .In rowbutton click even  I have wrote  cs code to make one page

label's visible true and bind another gridview2 with datasour..

my grid view event is running and reading the code while running but my page label's

visiblity is not happening and gridview2 is not displaying with data though datasource

shows data..Please help..

```
  protected void GridView3_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
   {
       int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
       GridViewRow selectedRow = GridView3.Rows[index];
       DateTime frmdt = this.DateRangePicker2.FromDate;
       DateTime Tomdt = this.DateRangePicker2.ToDate;
    if (e.CommandName == "btnPrvViewp")
    {

        if (selectedRow.Cells[1].Text == "Indirect Process" && selectedRow.Cells[2].Text == "SAP")
        {
            this.lbel1.Text  = "Productivity Detaisl for the period " + frmdt + " To " + Tomdt;
            this.lbel1.Visible = true;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str2);
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("ViewProductivity", conn);
            com.Parameters.Add("@fromDate", SqlDbType.DateTime ).Value = frmdt;
            com.Parameters.Add("@ToDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Tomdt;
            conn.Open();
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataReader readerp = com.ExecuteReader();
            GridView2.DataSource = readerp;
            GridView2.DataBind();

            readerp.Close();

        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the label and gridview inside the selected row. Your code should look like this:

```
protected void GridView3_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    GridViewRow selectedRow = GridView3.Rows[index];
    DateTime frmdt = this.DateRangePicker2.FromDate;
    DateTime Tomdt = this.DateRangePicker2.ToDate;
    if (e.CommandName == "btnPrvViewp")
    {

        if (selectedRow.Cells[1].Text == "Indirect Process" && selectedRow.Cells[2].Text == "SAP")
        {
            Label lbel1 = selectedRow.FindControl("lbel1") as Label;
            GridView GridView2 = selectedRow.FindControl("GridView2") as GridView;
            lbel1.Text = "Productivity Detaisl for the period " + frmdt + " To " + Tomdt;
            lbel1.Visible = true;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str2);
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("ViewProductivity", conn);
            com.Parameters.Add("@fromDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = frmdt;
            com.Parameters.Add("@ToDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Tomdt;
            conn.Open();
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataReader readerp = com.ExecuteReader();
            GridView2.DataSource = readerp;
            GridView2.DataBind();

            readerp.Close();

        }

    }
}
```